# spray-cache not showing new elements after adding

Tags: scala, spray

My aim is to add elements to an existing spray-cache instance. This does not happen without any obvious reason or error.

My approach is to use available scala-future api to get intermediate results and available mapping methods of scala-futures (map, foreach) to "unpack" data produced by futures.

Here's code showing my approach (it is complete and can be instantly tested):

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.caching.LruCache

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

case class Cached(elements: List[Int])

object TestApp extends App {

  //ignore these, just so that cache gets some execution context
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestApp")
  implicit def dispatcher = system.dispatcher

  val cache = LruCache[Cached]()
  val cacheKey = "test"

  cache(cacheKey) {
    new Cached(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
  }

  def merge(key: String, mergeList: List[Int]) = {
    // get the existing cache content
    cache.get(key).foreach { cachedFuture =>
      // wait until it is actually returned
      cachedFuture.onComplete {
        // merge extracted elements with mergeList
        case Success(cached) =>
          val mergedCache = cached.elements ++ mergeList

          // before re-constructing cache element, remove it from spray-cache
          cache.remove(key).foreach { removeFuture =>
            // as soon as remove is complete
            removeFuture.onComplete {
              // re-construct cache element
              case Success(_) =>
                // actually reconstructing cache element with the key
                cache(key) { new Cached(mergedCache) }
              case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
            }
          }
        case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
      }
    }
  }

  // merge new element 5
  merge(cacheKey, List(5))
  cache.get(cacheKey).map(_.onComplete {
    case Success(cached) =>
      // new cache should contain 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
      println(s"Cache content is: ${cached.elements.mkString("; ")}")
      sys.exit(0)
    case Failure(ex) => println(ex); sys.exit(0)
  })
}
```

Comment: This is a race condition between the merge call and the subsequent get. If you insert a `Thread.sleep(100)` between merge and the the `cache.get` it works (though this only a hack). If you want to be sure the merge has finished you need to return a future from merge which is completed when the final merge update has been completed.

Comment: Btw. by using `cache.get().foreach` you are silently ignoring the case where the cache doesn't contain an entry yet.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think your `merge` operation is safe if several merges to the same key may run at the same time. That's because the cache doesn't support atomic updates, i.e. a concurrent run may execute something between cache.remove and the re-adding of the new value.

Comment: Ok so I could synchronize either the whole merge def or some parts inside of it - this is solvable. What I would like to reach, is a solution where I could use merge def synchronously (i.e. without futures) in the code using merge. I really don't want to use Await.result()

Comment: Maybe this is possible, the actual cache updates happen synchronously (i.e. don't return a future), you just need to map the previous future to add the new elements and put that back in the cache.

Comment: Maybe I should also add that this is not what this cache solution was invented for. As you are using the LRUCache, previous entries may get evicted depending on what else uses the cache. Why don't you go with a simple Map or a ConcurrentHashMap (depending on the access patterns) and just put those Futures in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working solution solving the issues I had with the code above.

I adapted some suggestions from [jrudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7647/jrudolph) in particular

- solve race condition between merge call and subsequent get
- solve ignoring case where *cache.get()* does not contain entry yet
- solve thread-safety of merge operation

What I was not able to solve, is the usage of *Await.result(...)* to make *def merge* to appear synchronous to the "outside world".

Regarding the comment of [jrudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7647/jrudolph) regarding using *Map* instead of *LruCache* he is principally correct. In my particular use case tho I chose *LruCache* because the actual application is putting only couple of keys in the Cache but the *elements: List[Int]* wrapped within *Cached* is actually huge complex collection that should get evicted if application adds too many keys at some point.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.caching.LruCache

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

case class Cached(elements: List[Int])

object TestApp extends App {

  //ignore these, just so that cache gets some execution context
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestApp")
  implicit def dispatcher = system.dispatcher

  val cache = LruCache[Cached]()
  val cacheKey = "test"

  cache(cacheKey) {
    new Cached(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
  }

  def merge(key: String, mergeList: List[Int]) = {
    // get the existing cache content
    val mergeResult: Future[Cached] = cache.get(key) match {
      case Some(cacheFuture) => cacheFuture.flatMap { case cached =>
          recreateCacheKey(key, Cached(cached.elements ++ mergeList))
      }
      case None => recreateCacheKey(key, Cached(mergeList))
    }

    // await result so that users of the def merge get impression that this def is synchronous
    Await.result(mergeResult, 5 seconds)
  }

  // synchronized should eliminate issue with thread-safety of cache modifications
  private def recreateCacheKey(cacheKey: String, newCached: Cached) = synchronized {
      val cacheRecreationFuture = cache.remove(cacheKey)
        .fold(cache(cacheKey) { newCached })(_.flatMap(removedFuture => cache(cacheKey, () => Future { newCached })))
      cacheRecreationFuture
  }

  private def printCacheContent = {
    cache.get(cacheKey).map(_.onComplete {
      case Success(cached) =>
        // new cache should contain 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        println(s"Cache content is: ${cached.elements.mkString("; ")}")
        sys.exit(0)
      case Failure(ex) => println(ex); sys.exit(0)
    })
  }

  /*****************/
  /* EXECUTE STUFF */
  /*****************/

  // merge new element 5
  merge(cacheKey, List(5))
  printCacheContent
}
```